# How do I scrape photos and videos with Pyrogram or Telethon?

Tags: telegram, telethon, py-telegram-bot-api, pyrogram

How do I scrape photos or videos from a group on Telegram using either Pyrogram or Telethon? I know how to make a client and so forth, but not sure which functions to call (I have already read the documentation).

I want the videos as mp4 files, and photos as jpg or jpeg.

Comment: Well if you've read the complete documentation you should have seen the methods you can use for that. Please include a [mre].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Client.get_chat_history()` in Pyrogram and use offset argument to get all messages.
Then check if messages has video or photo and if they have it download it using `Message.download()`.